# URGENT - used git clean -xdf, lost everything need something to recover the files

Tags: ubuntu, git, data-recovery, recovery

I was doing some coding and working on an environment when I read a command that would help me sort my libraries in a conda environment -> git clean -xdf . Dumb me just pasted on the terminal, lost everything. I have my final thesis work and draft there as well as the codes. Things I will need to modify very soon and don't have copies (dumb again) as well as many recent photos of priceless moments.

Tomorrow I am also expected to present some results to be able to start my PhD. Can someone please, PLEASE, help me recover the files, most of them. (If installed software too it would be amazing but at this moment I am happy with anything).

If I can give any extra information let me know.

Comment: `git clean` removes untracked files that have not been added to the git repo with `git add .` were you using an IDE or anything?

Comment: Sorry for not knowing much, but I don't believe I even have a gitt repo. I just pasted the line on my terminal, like home folder, and the line deleted almost everything

Comment: Oh I see. Well in that case you'll need to use a file recovery program like Recuva, extundelete, etc.

Comment: With it being Ubuntu, Recuva is not an option. I would try TestDisk. [How to use TestDisk](https://vitux.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-through-testdisk/)

Comment: I'm trying, from the live usb I guess

Comment: It's not a physical install of Ubuntu? You were running a live cd?

Comment: I had real Ubuntu, but I'm now running the live to try not to touch in the "real" ubuntu partition to not mess up future recovery I guess

Comment: Did any of that work?

Comment: Hire a professional. You have lost important data and don't know how to proceed. Don't take risks.

Comment: Hey all, thank you for everything. I tried to back up with Testdisk from the live usb, unfortunately I somehow saved it in the wrong place and made it impossible to recover. Meanwhile talked with someone who taught me a lot about this and now I'm using FreeFileSync to always have a backup.  Lessons where learned, I hope

Comment: @T.Silva Well, rather than relying on something else, you could just commit more often.